# Firebase Authorization Error

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I created a register activity with Firebase Authentication, but when I ran the application and clicked on the sign up button, nothing happened. Only the progress dialog, just rotating and it didn't even signup.

Here is my code:

```
public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText mNameField;
    private EditText mEmailField;
    private EditText mPasswordField;

    private Button mRegisterBtn;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

    private ProgressDialog mProgress;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users");

        mProgress = new ProgressDialog(this);

        mNameField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameFied);
        mEmailField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailField);
        mPasswordField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordField);
        mRegisterBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.registerBtn);

        mRegisterBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startRegister();
            }
        });
    }

    private void startRegister() {
        final String name = mNameField.getText().toString().trim();
        String email = mEmailField.getText().toString().trim();
        String password = mPasswordField.getText().toString().trim();

        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(name) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(email) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){

            mProgress.setMessage("Signing up...please wait");
            mProgress.show();

            mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {


                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()){
                        String user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                        DatabaseReference current_user_db = mDatabase.child(user_id);
                        current_user_db.child("name").setValue(name);
                        current_user_db.child("image").setValue("default");

                        mProgress.dismiss();

                        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                        mainIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(mainIntent);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(name) && TextUtils.isEmpty(email) && TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "do not leave any field empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know what I did wrong.

Here are my gradle dependencies:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.2.0'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to add a `OnFailureListener` to see what exception or error you are getting.

```
 mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {


                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()){
                        String user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                        DatabaseReference current_user_db = mDatabase.child(user_id);
                        current_user_db.child("name").setValue(name);
                        current_user_db.child("image").setValue("default");

                        mProgress.dismiss();

                        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                        mainIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(mainIntent);
                    }
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Log.i("Firebase Exception -> ",e.getMessage());
                        }});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating user with

```
createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
```

but you never sign-in. You also need to sign in after creating user with

```
signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
```

and in that add data to your database.

And I would suggest to update your repository and decencies also.